# Get the most recent record for each user where value is 'K', action id is null or its state is 1

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have the following tables in SQL Server:

```
user_id,  value,  date,    action_id
----------------------------------
1          A   1/3/2012     null
1          K   1/4/2012     null
1          B   1/5/2012     null
2          X   1/3/2012     null
2          K   1/4/2012     1
3          K   1/3/2012     null
3          L   1/4/2012     2
3          K   1/5/2012     3
4          K   1/3/2012     null


action_id, state
----------------------------------
1           0
2           1
3           1
4           0
5           1
```

I need to return the most recent record for each user where the value is 'K', the action id is either null or its state is set to 1. Here's the result set I want:

```
user_id,  value,  date,    action_id
----------------------------------
3          K   1/5/2012     3
4          K   1/3/2012     null
```

For user_id 1, the most recent value is B and its action id is null, so I consider this the most recent record, but it's value is not K.

For user_id 2, the most recent value is K, but action id 1 has state 0, so I fallback to X, but X is not K.

user_id 3 and 4 are straightforward.

I'm interested in Linq to SQL query in ASP.NET, but for now T-SQL is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query would be :

```
Select Top 1 T1.* from Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2  T2
ON T1.action_id = T2.action_id
Where T1.Value = 'K' AND (T1.action_id is null or T2.state = 1)
Order by T1.date desc
```

LINQ Query :

```
var result  = context.Table1.Where(T1=> T1.Value == "K"
                        && (T1.action_id == null || 
                            context.Table2
                            .Where(T2=>T2.State == 1)
                            .Select(T2 => T2.action_id).Contains(T1.action_id)))
                        .OrderByDescending(T => T.date)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: I think you forgot the part where T1.action_id is null. Can you update both of those queries? The where clause in the T-SQL query should be "Where T1.value = 'K' and (T1.action_id is null or T2.state = 1)"

Comment: Visual Studio does not recognize T.T2.state in the where clause. :( There is no intellisense support for it. I get a compiler error. It actually won't display any of the columns in T2.

Answer (score 0):

This would select the top entries for all users as described in your specification, as opposed to `TOP 1` which just selects the most recent entry in the database. I'm assuming here that your tables are named `users` and `actions`:

```
WITH usersactions as 
  (SELECT 
       u.user_id, 
       u.value, 
       u.date, 
       u.action_id,
       ROW NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY u.date DESC, u.action_id DESC) as row
    FROM users u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN actions a ON u.action_id = a.action_id
    WHERE 
        u.value = 'K' AND 
        (u.action_id  IS NULL OR a.state = 1)
  )
SELECT * FROM usersactions WHERE row = 1
```

Or if you don't want to use a CTE:

```
SELECT * FROM  
  (SELECT 
       u.user_id, 
       u.value, 
       u.date, 
       u.action_id,
       ROW NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY u.date DESC, u.action_id DESC) as row
    FROM users u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN actions a ON u.action_id = a.action_id
    WHERE 
        u.value = 'K' AND 
        (u.action_id  IS NULL OR a.state = 1)
  ) useractions
WHERE row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will return desired result set:

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
             user_id
            ,value
            ,date
            ,action_id
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC) RowNum
        FROM
            testtable
        WHERE
            value = 'K'
    ) testtable
    WHERE
        RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following approach if user_id and date combination is unique
Make sure to get the order of predicates in the join to be able to use indexes:

```
    SELECT
        testtable.*
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                 user_id
                ,MAX(date) LastDate
            FROM
                testtable
            WHERE
                value = 'K'
            GROUP BY
                user_id
        ) tblLastValue
    INNER JOIN
        testtable
    ON
        testtable.user_id = tblLastValue.user_id
    AND
        testtable.date = tblLastValue.LastDate
```